# Loop stop after 3rd or less iteration & return results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a dynamic image's javascript URL link out from a list of URLs.
But when I using a `for` loop it stops at the 3rd iteration or less and returns the results back.

Not sure where it goes wrong. Can anybody here can point out the mistake?

(**Note:** The QT5 code is not written by me. It's from someone in this forum and I'm testing it out. I want to thank the person but can't find the thread.)

```
import os
import requests
import bs4 as bs
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
import sys
import urllib.request

get_all_pages_links_1 = ['http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p4', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p5', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p6', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p7', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p8', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p9', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p10', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p11', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p12', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p13', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p14', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p15', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p16', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p17', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p18', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p19', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p20', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p21', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p22', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p23', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p24', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p25', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p26', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p27', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p28', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p29', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p30', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p31', 'http://www.dm5.com/m1103555-p32']



##- Methods using Qt5 Class Acting as Broswse to render Javascript links

class Client(QWebEnginePage):

    def __init__(self,url):
        global app
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print("Load Finished")

    def Callable(self,data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()


dwn_link = []
for item003 in get_all_pages_links_1:
    url03 = item003
    print(url03)

    ## Use Qt5 Class to get Javascript links
    client_response = Client(url03)
    #print(client_response.html)
    soup_javascript = bs.BeautifulSoup(client_response.html, 'html.parser')
    #print(client_response.html)

    ##Use CSS selector method to point to the image link in html
    image_element = soup_javascript.select('#cp_image')
    for image in image_element:
        src_link = image['src']
        dwn_link.append(src_link)
    
    print(dwn_link)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274865/scrape-multiple-urls-using-qwebpage  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123406/loop-alway-stop-at-the-third-iteration  ?

Comment: Thanks, will test it out.